# Convert Windows Forms into an MMC SnapIn

Tags: winforms, mmc

I have a Windows Forms app, which I want to convert into an MMC snapin and display the form in one of the forms, the form has a few buttons and event handlers for button clicks etc.

Should I convert the winform into a user control, will my event handlers still work in this case?

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this MMC3? There's a good sample on MSDN, ["How-To Create a Snap-in That Uses WinForm View"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692744%28VS.85%29.aspx)